# Dont include library module in some flavors of multi-flavor app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have added flavors to my app and I have a couple library modules that are supposed go in certain flavors, one or multiple in each flavor

I have

```
flavor1
flavor2
flavor3
flavor4
```

then

```
library1
library2
library3
```

Is there a way where I can define what flavors compile with specific library modules?

Example:

```
flavor1
    include library2
flavor2
    include library1 & library3
flavor3
    include library3
```

Is this possible or would I have to have all this library code in the main code part?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, you can specify flavor specific dependencies in the main project

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    .....
    flavor1Implementation project(path: ':app:library1')
}
```